# Global /etc/profile setenv or export overwriting user settings in .profile

Tags: shell-script, centos, path, tcsh

I need to call a modified version of a program in `/home/user_name/bin` rather than the (older) version in `/opt/program_name/current` on a CentOS 5.3 cluster. The program creates a tcsh script using python and then executes that script.

I can overwrite the PATH to call the modified version of the program in `~/bin`, such that `which program_name` identifies the path to `~/bi`n. I have done this in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.tcshrc`, and `.cshrc`. However, each time the tcsh is executed, environmental variables from `/etc/profile` are loaded and the path gets reverted to `/opt/program_name/current`.

These program-specific variables are set when `/etc/profile.d/program_name.sh` is called by `/etc/profile`:

```
# /etc/profile 
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        . $i
    fi
done
unset i
```

Thus, when `program_name.sh` is called, the corresponding script is:

```
# /etc/profile.d/program_name.sh
setenv PATH ${PATH}:/opt/program_name/current
```

How can I prevent `/etc/profile` from being accessed by my user account?

I do not have su access and other users are still using the older version of the software in `/opt/program_name/current` so I can't update the software or modify settings in `/etc/profile.d/program_name.sh`

Answer (score 1):

tcsh doesn't spontaneously read `/etc/profile`, there must be something in the script causing this. A likely possibility (but not the only one) is that the script starts with `#!/bin/tcsh -l`, so tcsh acts as a login shell. That still won't cause it to read `/etc/profile`, but it will cause it to read `/etc/csh.login`, which may read other files (I don't know what CentOS ships in `csh.login` nor how your system administrators have customized it).

After reading `/etc/csh.login`, tcsh reads `~/.login`. Depending on how it's been configured, it may read `~/.login` before, after, or instead of `~/.tcshrc`. So be sure to try overriding `PATH` in `~/.tcshrc` as well.

If that doesn't work, modifying the Python script may be your best bet. If the code is in a module, you may be able to work around it by putting a wrapper module in `PYTHONPATH` that loads the original and makes a few changes.

If that fails, there is no easy way to “redirect” the access the program executable or to tcsh. This is possible in principle by using `LD_PRELOAD` to wrap around a few file access functions (if all the programs involved are dynamically linked and not set[ug]id), but it's a lot of work.

There may well be an easier way by hooking into the script somewhere, e.g. overriding one of the programs called near the beginning of the script with a function defined in your `.cshrc`. It's difficult to be more precise without seeing that script.

Comment: The problem of calling environmental variables when `tcsh` is invoked appears to be global and not limited to my script. I tried installing a local copy of `tcsh` in `~/bin/` and I set my PATH in `~/.bashrc` `~/.profile` `~/.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` to look in `~/bin` before `/bin`. As a result, `which tcsh` returns `/home/user_name/bin/tcsh` but when i type `tcsh` it still loads environmental variables from elsewhere.

Comment: @David Run `strace -eopen tcsh` to see what files it's reading.

Comment: `strace` isn't installed on the Cluster. When I run `strace -eopen tcsh` on the _head node_ I get back the paths I expect. In fact, `tcsh` behaves as expected when I initially log into the _head node_. I think that connecting to the _Sun Grid Cluster nodes_ is pulling global variables from `/etc/csh.cshrc`. I can't find the `setenv` variables specified elsewhere.  `/etc/csh.cshrc` executes `/etc/profile.d/*.csh` which contains the program-specific `setenv PATH ${PATH}:/opt/program_name/current` calls. These variables are set every time `tcsh` is called, overwriting my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to **not rely on `PATH`** but instead give the full path to `program_name`.

As for why it's sourcing /etc/profile, it must be called by either `/etc/csh.chsrc` or possibly `/etc/csh.login`.  For more info, see the `man` page for `tcsh`.  Specifically, look (search) for the sections *`Startup and shutdown`* and *`FILES`* in the man page.

From *Startup and shutdown*, this is the most relevant part:

> A login shell begins  by  executing  commands  from  the  system  files
>          `/etc/csh.cshrc`  and  `/etc/csh.login`/.   It  then  executes commands from
>          files in  the  user's  home  directory
>
> ...
>
> Non-login shells read only `/etc/csh.cshrc` and `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc`  on
>          startup.

And from *FILES* (which covers all *nix flavors):

> ```
>    /etc/csh.cshrc  Read first by every shell.  ConvexOS, Stellix and Intel
>                    use /etc/cshrc and  NeXTs  use  /etc/cshrc.std.   A/UX,
>                    AMIX,  Cray  and IRIX have no equivalent in csh(1), but
>                    read this file in tcsh anyway.  Solaris  2.x  does  not
>                    have it either, but tcsh reads /etc/.cshrc.  (+)
>    /etc/csh.login  Read  by  login shells after /etc/csh.cshrc.  ConvexOS,
>                    Stellix   and   Intel   use   /etc/login,   NeXTs   use
>                    /etc/login.std,  Solaris 2.x uses /etc/.login and A/UX,
>                    AMIX, Cray and IRIX use /etc/cshrc.
> ```